Manim Community: Color in Equation by Text
I have following Python code to display a matrix in Manim Community:
from manim import *

class Example(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        A = MathTex(
            r"A="
            r"\begin{pmatrix}"
            r"a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots  & a_{1n}\\"
            r"a_{21} & a_{22} & \dots  & a_{2n}\\"
            r"\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\"
            r"a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \dots  & a_{nn}"
            r"\end{pmatrix}"
        ).center()

        self.play(Write(A))


I'd like to give every "a" the same color (like red for example).
I know I can display the indices, and then color each "a" individually by index, but this gets increasingly tideous for bigger equations.
Is there a way to do such things smarter, like a color in by text, or by iterating over the equation?

There exists set_color_by_tex in MathTex but you need to carefully read the Substrings and parts documentation where it says

Note that set_color_by_tex() colors the entire substring containing the Tex, not just the specific symbol or Tex expression

So when applied on a MathTex the whole equation is colored. As this is not what you want, you can use the substrings_to_isolate parameter to MathTex
An (almost) working example looks like this
class Example(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        A = MathTex(
            r"A=a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots  & a_{1n}\\a_{21} & a_{22} & \dots  & a_{2n}\\\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \dots  & a_{nn}",
            substrings_to_isolate="a"
        ).center()
        
        A.set_color_by_tex("a", RED)

        self.play(Write(A))

As you can see I removed \begin{pmatrix} & \end{pmatrix} to make it work.
Maybe you can follow up on their Github to see if applying substrings_to_isolate on a matrix MathTex should work or not

Thank you for the answer. (: I guess I'll just color them in manually.
